# Are there any ferry companies operating between Russian East ports and Japan?

Tags: russia, japan, ferries, asia

I'm interested in visiting the Japan after some Russian Far East trip.
I'm searching for the sea ways to the Japan. Can you help me with that?

---

Update: I'm searching some extremal variants not from Vladivostok

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there are at least two. How far far east do you want?

Slightly far east:

- There is a ferry between Vladivostok and Takaoka.
- There should be a ferry between Vladivostok and Toyama.
- (There may be a ferry between Vladivostok and Niigata but reports say it's discontinued for now)

Extremely far east:

- There is a ferry between Sakhalin (Korsakov) and far northern Hokkaido (Wakkanai).

If it's something off the beaten path you're looking for I've been wanting to do the Sahkhalin-Japan crossing for a few years. If it's something practial you're looking for that may not be it (-:

Here are some useful links:

- http://ease.com/~randyj/rjjapanx.htm
- http://wikitravel.org/en/Toyama#By_boat
- http://www.waytorussia.net/FarEast/Vladivostok/Transport.html

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Updated with more details but didn't want to plagiarise the sources especially since some of the the dates, times, and prices may not be up to date.

Comment: I believe the Sakhalin-Wakkanai ferry ceased some years before covid. IIRC the Japanese company ceased operating it and the next year a Russian company operated on the route, but they also gave it up after only one season. This is off the top of my head.