# Is it possible to travel the route Kamchatka-Kurils-Hokkaido alone at the end of Sept-Oct?

Tags: japan, transportation, russia, ferries, extreme-tourism

I would like to travel, alone, Kamchatka-Kurils-Hokkaido at the end of Sept-Oct. I speak Russian and have done quite some extreme travels before. Most of the sites refer to the non-Hokkaido route:

1. Vladivostok-main land Japan;
2. Sakhalin to Wakanai (Hokkaido).

They indicate that the ferries stop sometime late summer.

Is the route from Kamchatka to Japan via Kuril islands possible?
There should be occasional ferries/fishing boats from Kamchatka to Severo-Kurisk, other Kuril islands all the way to the Yuzhno-Kurilsk and then to Japan.
I was in Shiretoko in the winter and saw that many Russians come there somehow.
But how, is it only during the summer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any ferry companies operating between Russian East ports and Japan?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/802/are-there-any-ferry-companies-operating-between-russian-east-ports-and-japan)

Comment: No, that post does not cover Kurils, and from Vladivostok there are only ferries to the Mainland Japan, not Hokkaido.

Comment: @tanja would you mind to detail a little bit more on what you intend with "is this route possible"? It's seems a little bit generic. Thank you an welcome!

Comment: @Geeo.Thanx. It seems that it is possible in the summer, but not off-season. There should be occasional ferries to Severo-kurisk,etc islands all the way to the Yuzhno-kurilsk and then to Japan. I was in Wakkanai and saw that many Russians come there somehow. But how, only during the summer?

Comment: @tanja so you are basically interested in **only** using ferries while heading down to Hokkaido and visiting the Kurilis. You are not looking for small planes that may do the same route, right?

Comment: @Geeo. I did not see any plane suggestions. Also, I suppose it is a matter of budget. I believe there should be some smaller fishing trailers or similar as the area is famous for fishing. Furthermore, I believe the last part, can be trafficked only by the sea.

Comment: @tanja I see. It would be super awesome if you would include all this details in your question by editing it so that people may have a clearer idea of what is asked! Thank you so much!

Comment: @tanja fair, indeed I hesitated. Just to make it clear, how flexible are you regarding the order of the trip? In other words, would you want to access Kurils either from Katchatka or Hokkaido (you can edit your question in this case), or do you want to absolutely go Kamchatka>Kurils>Hokkaido?

Comment: @vince The order is important as the question is if there are any other possible nicer/more exciting routes from Kamchatka to Japan, not only via air, described in different forums. I travel fr Hong Kong and want to spend some weeks in Kamchatka first, and finish my trip in Japan, where I am used to travel.

Comment: I am keenly interested in this trip - I've wanted to do something similar for years.

Comment: I'll try to find more specific information about your question. Can you say, are there any sites you've already visited?

Answer (score 8):

The best I can figure there is not a route of any ferry that goes Petropavlovsk → Kurils → Hokkaido.

It is possible to hop a ferry from Petropavlovsk → Vladivostok → Korsakov (Sakhalin) → Hokkaido using [Sasco](http://www.sasco.ru/) and [Heartland Ferry](http://www.heartlandferry.jp/russian/index4-1.html) but the schedule for both stop on September 30th.

According to another article [Sasco provides ferry service to Kurils](http://www.sakhalin.info/ykurilsk/85404/) which is confirmed by [Sakhalin Region Transport Ministry](http://mintrans.admsakhalin.ru/page.php?id=41) and it runs year round from Sakhalin. The ship stops at major Kuril islands and runs weekly in the summer and every second week Oct-Feb. There is an exact timetable on the website of the Ministry, see above, but it is in Russian. The Kamchatka's corresponding ministry doesn't provide any additional information on the subject.

You also could call up [Petropavlovsk's Port](http://port.kamchatka.ru/about/) to find out if any of the ships actually go your route and can take you on board but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: Thanx! I give up this idea for now. It was complicated but doable via Sakhalin > Wakkanai. But then, the whole point was to visit Kurils and not only to get from Russia to Japan. (for that I would take a flight Kamchatka > Vladivistok(s7) > Japan(aeroflot). I also red that in the Unesco directive for this region(both Russia nd Japan) is to develop the entrance point to Japan via Kurils, but it seems to take time. Finally, my conclusion today, after some dayy of research in different languages, is that the north of Hokkaido is amazing enough(similar too) and even cheaper, than visiting Kurils.

Comment: *the Unesco directive for this region* and since when "superpowers" follow the UNESCO directives when it comes to contested territories?

Comment: Hearland ferry seems to have quit the route to Sakhalin but an alternative ferry may operate instead. [I have a question about this seeking more details.](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72791)